# Run command on region AucTeX

Tags: key-bindings, auctex

I would like to run `force-compile` (see [Run TeX-command-run-all when there are no changes in .tex-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40850/run-tex-command-run-all-when-there-are-no-changes-in-tex-file)) on a region of my LaTeX document.

```
(defun force-compile ()
"Set the file modification times on the current file, then call
TeX-command-sequence.
This forces a complete recompilation of the document, even if the 
source
(.tex) is older than any existing outputs (.pdf etc)."
(interactive)
(set-file-times (buffer-file-name)) ;; sets mod time to current time
(TeX-command-sequence t t))
```

I was already able to bind force-compile to `C-c C-a` which then compiles the file even when there are no changes in the file itself. Now I want to be able to do the same on a region of the file.

How can i use `force-compile` on a region of the LaTeX-file?

Comment: I'm not sure what the most elegant way to do this is, but you could create a new function (`force-compile-region`) with the same definition, but replace `(TeX-command sequence t t )` with `(TeX-command-region)`.

Comment: That worked perfectly when using `(TeX-command-run-all-region)`. One last thing: I need to save the region of the buffer and not the buffer itself. Is there a command to it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to save only part of a buffer - it's all the same file. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @quark Maybe you are looking for `write-region`?

Comment: i tried `write-region` but i get the error `Wrong number of arguments: write-region, 0`. What for a argument do i need to provide? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the help for `write-region`, `C-h f write-region`. It takes three arguments, the start and end of the region (`(region-beginning)` and `(region-end)` should work), and the name of a file to write the region to. You don't want to use the current file, or you'll end up over-writing your entire file with just the active region, erasing everything else.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment thread, the following solution appears to work:

```el
(defun force-compile-region ()
  "Set the file modification times on the current file, then call
   TeX-command-run-all-region. This forces a complete recompilation of 
   the document, even if the source (.tex) is older than any 
   existing outputs (.pdf etc)."
  (interactive)
  (set-file-times (buffer-file-name)) ;; sets mod time to current time
  (TeX-command-run-all-region))
```